# Data dump filetype for not-yet-existant SQL database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, web-scraping

A friend wants to start scraping data for a data-heavy site he wants me to try to build. I'm a (relatively new) Rails developer and don't know much about the data side of all this. If he's contracting out the scraping, any idea what sort of format can/should I get the data in to easily import it into a PostgreSQL database once I get the site started up?

Hope this isn't too vague a question. I don't know where to start looking for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV file format is compatible with almost any database systems and it is quite a good starter.  Even, if you change your mind later, as for what database system you'll use, you don't have to worry too much about changing the format.

If you thinking about data mining, then probably NoSQL database systems can be a better solution (MongoDB, CouchDB, etc.).  Then, then file format can be JSON as well.

Comment: Thanks! So specifically, the friend is trying to gather data on gun violence in the US (type of crime, gun, etc, as well as time, location, perpetrator details, etc). Potentially a very wide body of data. Does that sound like a job for Mongo or something, cause of the unpredictability? Is CSV OK for that?

Comment: @Sasha - if you properly design the CSV file, then is should not be any problem.